# Need to find the MEAN of Col 6 based on the value of Col 5 (Col 5 is 0/1)

Tags: python

I have a spreadsheet with 10 columns and 727 obs. Col 5 is 0/1 whether a student is economically disadvantaged or not. I need to find the mean of Col 6 (test score) based on whether the student is economically disadvantaged or not. Help!

Comment: Use `pandas`, it has built-in methods for aggregating data like this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly:

> 1. First you need to import your spreadsheet into python with csv module.
> 2. Then you need "for" loop to sum all your col per person.
> 3. Calculate mean of each obs.
> 4. If result greater than half of total number, get to your student 1 ;else get them 0 .